# How can I run Excel solver in a loop and collect the output for a series of constraint variable?

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I am trying to find out the Efficient Frontier for a stock portfolio.

My objective is to minimise Risk (Sd in %)
Constraints: 
1. Total weight of the portfolio should be 100% and
2. A given Expected return in %

I want to find out a the minimum risk figures for all the given expected returns ranging from 5% to 75% in integer interval

I am new to VBA

**So far I have done this:**

I have tried a lot of other things. The following seems to be somewhat working:

Option Base 1

```
Sub MSolve()
Dim r As Integer, i As Integer

Dim result(1 To 5)
i = 1
Set given = Range("'[portfolio data-1.xlsm]Analysis'!$M$14:$M$18")
Set output = Range("'[portfolio data-1.xlsm]Analysis'!$N$14:$N$18")

For i = 1 To 5

SolverReset
SolverAdd CellRef:="$D$3:$D$7"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$D$8", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="100%"
SolverAdd CellRef:="Portfolio_Return", Relation:=2, FormulaText:=given(i, 1)
SolverOK SetCell:="Portfolio_Risk", MaxMinVal:=2, Valueof:=0, ByChange:="$D$3:$D$7", Engine:=1
SolverSolve
SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
SolverSave SaveArea:=Range("G15")
output(i, 1) = Range("G15")
SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
Next i
SolverReset
End Sub
```

But the problem is after every run I have to manually Click Ok on the Solver result pop-up. If there is any better way to do this, kindly help

Comment: What problem are you encountering? How does what you have done fail to do what you want? You need to be more specific.

Comment: By the way, `Option Base 1` is widely considered to be a design-mistake in the VBA language. It potentially makes code unnecessarily hard to interpret. I would recommend against using it. You actually aren't, since you explicitly give the lower bound to `result()`. Why have a superfluous, somewhat disrespectable line?

Comment: I am unable to make the solver take input from the range of Portfolio_Risk, the return is always the existing value in the Portfolio_Return.

Comment: Also when I am entering the function it is giving 10 consecutive prompts with unexpected error, when the number of runs required is only five. It is the same prompt where solver asks whether to keep the solver solution or go back to the original data. Pleas help. Thank you

Comment: It doesn't seem change much. I am getting the same return for a solved variable.
I am trying to fill the second column through Solver:
Portfolio Return vs. Portfolio Risk
0.06 0.07 0.08 0.09 0.10 
I am assigning the whole range as given to use in the function. Is that the best way to do it?

Comment: It appears you are trying to use constraints from a different tab, maybe even a different workbook (`given`). Solver requires all information to be on the same tab.

Comment: Some sample data would help me to make recommendations.